# Filtering invoice collection by created_at in magento

Tags: magento, collections, filtering

I'm trying to find a way to filter the results of getInvoiceCollection in the function below:

```
// "eachInvoice" is each of the Invoice object of the order "$orders"
if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
    foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $eachInvoice) {
        $invoiceIncrementId = $eachInvoice->getIncrementId();
    }
}
```

Can adding the filter below to $order->getInvoiceCollection()

```
 $order->getInvoiceCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
    'from' => $from_date,
    'to' => $today, 
    'date' => true,));
```

So the entire function would be, is the correct way to do this, it doesn't seem like its right.

```
// "eachInvoice" is each of the Invoice object of the order "$orders"
    if ($order->hasInvoices()) {
    foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection()$order->getInvoiceCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array( 'from' => $from_date,
    'to' => $today, 'date' => true,)) as $eachInvoice) {
        $invoiceIncrementId = $eachInvoice->getIncrementId();
    }
}
```

Whats the "correct way" to go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the increment ids as is shown in your sample code there is no need to loop:

```
$invoiceCollection = $order->getInvoiceCollection();

$invoiceCollection
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
            'from'  => $from,
            'to'    => $to,                    
        ));

$incrementIds = $invoiceCollection->getColumnValues('increment_id');
```